# Where does `abcde` output files?

Tags: linux, debian, ripping, cd, abcde

I ran `abcde` on an audio CD, when in the working directory `$HOME`. Now I can't find the outputed files in my home directory. Where do they go by default? I'm using the default `abcde` installation on Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Now I can't find the output files in my home directory. Where do they go?

> **Output**
>
> Each track is, by default, placed in a separate file named after the
> track in a subdirectory named after the artist under the current
> directory. This can be modified using the `OUTPUTFORMAT` and
> `VAOUTPUTFORMAT` variables in your `abcde.conf`. Each file is given an
> extension identifying its compression format, 'vorbis' for '.ogg',
> '.mp3', '.flac', '.spx', '.mpc', '.aac' or '.wav'.

Source: [abcde(1) - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/abcde)